# UsbDeviceBuilder and String Descriptors problem

Tags: rust, embedded

How do I set the string descriptors on a usb device UsbDeviceBuilder in Rust?

In the previously version I just

```
let mut usb_dev = UsbDeviceBuilder::new(&usb_bus, UsbVidPid(0x16c0, 0x27dd))
        .manufacturer("No Name Brand")
        .product("Serial port")
        .serial_number("1234567890")
        .device_class(2)
        .build();
```

And In the 0.3 I tried to

```
let descriptors = [StringDescriptors::new(0x0009.into())
        .manufacturer("No Name Brand")
        .product("Serial port")
        .serial_number("1234567890")];
let mut usb_dev = UsbDeviceBuilder::new(&usb_bus, UsbVidPid(0x16c0, 0x27dd)).device_class(2).strings(&descriptors).build();
```

But I get an error trying to set the strings and then build. How should I build the usb device? It works fine if I just ignore setting the string descriptions.

The error I get is

```
error[E0599]: no method named `build` found for enum `Result` in the current scope
   --> boards\rp-pico\examples\pico_usb_serial.rs:115:120
    |
115 |     let mut usb_dev = UsbDeviceBuilder::new(&usb_bus, UsbVidPid(0x16c0, 0x27dd)).device_class(2).strings(&descriptors).build();
    |                       ---------------------------------------------------------- ---------------                       ^^^^^ method not found in `Result<UsbDeviceBuilder<'_, UsbBus>, BuilderError>`
    |                       |                                                          |
    |                       |                                                          method `build` is available on `usb_device::device::UsbDeviceBuilder<'_, rp_pico::rp2040_hal::usb::UsbBus>` 
    |                       method `build` is available on `usb_device::device::UsbDeviceBuilder<'_, rp_pico::rp2040_hal::usb::UsbBus>`
    |
note: the method `build` exists on the type `usb_device::device::UsbDeviceBuilder<'_, rp_pico::rp2040_hal::usb::UsbBus>`
```

Comment: *"But I get an error trying to set the strings and then build"* – Please always include the full error message as [formatted](/help/formatting) text!

Comment: I updated the question with the error message

Comment: Have you read [ch02-09 of the book "Recoverable Errors with `Result`"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) yet? It explains how you can handle `Result` and friends.